# What level of politeness/respect should a customer use towards a shop owner?

Tags: keigo, email, sonkeigo

I made a purchase at a store and received an email from the shop owner.

What level of respect/politeness should my reply be, in addition to using 丁寧形 throughout? For example, how should I choose between 〜てもらう and 〜ていただく? Should I use 尊敬語 and 謙譲語? Should I address the store owner as Xさん or Xさま?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your style or relationship between the shop owner, but you are not to be blamed as long as you use regular polite style.